# thumbs.db file error

Tags: console, thumbnails, thumbs.db

i have a console program. at some screen when it needs to display, then an error comes as "Resetting file Thumbs.db" and the console window closes. how to solve this error. please help

Comment: Please can you add more information. What software is it you are using? Is it something you have written yourself?

Comment: yes, it is a software which uses foxpro as database and is written in foxpro

Comment: If you have written it yourself, then Stack Overflow would be a better place to ask, **but** you would need to supply *much* more information and the code that was failing.

Comment: does DOS also uses Thumbs.db file? but it is created by Windows then how could DOS use it? is it possbile? or it would depend on my code ?

Comment: when, am running it one system then it does not shows error, but on another system it gives this reset thumbs.db error? so i think that there's no error in my code.

Comment: It would depend on your code. It's just a file, but if your code is trying to read all files in the directory it won't have the format you expect and your code will fail (as indeed it has).

Comment: `Thumbs.db` was introduced by Windows XP. MS-DOS _never_ uses it.

Answer (score 0):

If thumbs.db is a system file, try changing the properties so it's not. If it's an empty file, then delete it. Also, if you run your program while Windows Explorer has the same folder open, there may be a file access conflict.